# Where do I put "WSGIPassAuthorization On"?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to see the Authorization header in Django, using mod_wsgi.  I read that Apache holds back the Authorization header by default, I've put << WSGIPassAuthorization On >> in my Apache VirtualHost block and . . . nada.

How do I figure out where to put this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put it at same place as WSGIScriptAlias and it should work fine.

Comment: Actually, it does.  Failure masked by another bug.  Also, Django users should note this comes through request.META as 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'.

Comment: I have put it just before WSGIScriptAlias, but it had no effect.

I also checked /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and all required modules were marked to be loaded.

Comment: Is WSGIPassAuthorization supported for VirtualHosts? I tried it on [Amazon EC2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664082/missing-http-authorization-at-amazon-ec2-django-instance), but it did not work...

Comment: As noted in the documentation for mod_wsgi, the configuration contexts it can be used in are server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess. So it can be used pretty well anywhere. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPassAuthorization http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your EC2, go to etc/httpd/conf.d folder and open wsgi.conf file. Insert the code within VirtualHost DOM:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: For mod_wsgi you shouldn't need both of these. You only need ``WSGIPassAuthorization``. The rewrite rules can be used separately if needing to get the information through to an old school CGI script though.

Answer (score 0):

in folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available` open your config file, for example `mySite.conf` and then add `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to it as follows:

```
        ...
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIPassAuthorization On

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/X/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess sepanta_dev python-path=/home/X python-home=/home/X/venv
        ...
```