# Authorization header field absent in request.headers() and request.META when using Apache, Preflight CORS error in browser when using custom header

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, apache2

I have my Rest Framework API's up and running on an AWS EC2 instance. I have set up Apache and added SSL certificate.
I'm using my own custom token authentication.

1. **Passing Authorization as header** - On doing post request from **both Postman and React**, the header is not received in `request.headers("Authorization")` and `request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]`.
2. **Passing Authorization2 or x-api-key as header** -

- Works fine from Postman
- On React, browser throws error `Access to fetch at 'https://www.myapi.live/api/project/add/8/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization2 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

I have already tried including Access-control-origin Header in React and setting django-cors-headers at backend. But it doesn't help.

3. **Passing Authorization as header but exposing runserver at `0.0.0.0:8000`** instead of apache https url-

- Works in Postman
- Works in React too

Here's my `000-default.conf` in both `sites-enabled` and `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.myapi.live
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/django/project
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
Alias /static /home/ubuntu/django/project/static
<Directory /home/ubuntu/django/project/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/ubuntu/django/project/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/ubuntu/django/project python-home=/home/ubuntu/django/myenv
WSGIProcessGroup project
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/django/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.myapi.live
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This question could use more structure and some trimming (e.g. the value of the token is not relevant).  It is very hard to follow right now.  Are you trying to say that when you expose the app directly on 8000 things work right from react, but when you go through apache you don't get the authorization header?

Comment: [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17018586/2395796) you need to configure Apache to not strip the `Authorization` header.

Comment: Thanks for correcting @AndrewBacker. I trimmed the question now. 
Yes, exposing on 8000 makes it work from react, but from apache it doesn't work from react. ( neither from postman too ). Apache is somehow stripping the Authorization header.

Comment: @AndrewBacker That's why I shifted to custom header and tried Authorization2..that works in apache. But from postman only. From react it still doesn't and throws the cors preflight request error in browser console..

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I agree.. If somehow I stop apache from stripping the Authorization header, it's sorted.. I shared my `000-default.conf` file can you suggest any changes?

Answer (score 1):

So I added `WSGIPassAuthorization On` to my `apache.conf` file which resides in the parent directory just outside of `sites-enabled`. Doing these changes made it work like a charm and apache no longer strips the `Authorization` header.

Just in case this can be of help to someone else in future! Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question and precisely tell what should be the content of the apache.conf file? I am having the same issue

Comment: I meant can you show the apache.conf file in your answer.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9781171/12661847 and this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-apache-server-with-django-for-deployment-on-virtual-machine